# Read Metastock Download Data Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does anyone have any idea how I can open and read data from the Metastock downloader, I would like to read all the symbols from the file and I'm struggling to parse it - the file downloaded is named "PriceRepository.MSPR01" has anyone dealt with this before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have looked into the MSLocal data format, a long time ago, then gave up...

There are allegedly a couple of "flavours" of MetaStock MSLocal data, they are in their proprietry database format(s) and MetaStock haven't released a new MDK despite promising one for over a decade.  Note: This is a database, so it's not just a matter of reading a file worth of data for one instrument.

Re-reading from my incomplete notes from a long time ago, I found the basic file structure (of one format) is a 433byte header section, then a lot of 16454byte "lines" (16454 = 38 x 433) with each line starting "<<<PH", and then a "chunk" of footer/metadata at the end of the file.

There are multiple lines in the data which contains the symbol names or tickers, which are pretty straightforward to extract, but I'm going to assume you want more information than just the names of the securities in the file?

At the time, I guessed the information in the line header placeholder, "<<<PH ... PH>>>" described the contents of that line of data??  Where I figured the line had OHLCVOI data, it's probably in 8byte chunks??

It's not the whole answer to your problem, but parsing the file is going to be a major step in the final solution.

The easiest solution is to use the Downloader to convert the data into a folder containing either CSV or the well-known legacy format data, and then deal with it however you please, or find another data vendor.